# spring aop resources

Tags: java, spring, aop

I am new to (Spring) AOP and I would like to get some suggestions about useful resources to learn. I have already been through Spring Documentation and I found it quite difficult to understand in some respects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found these series of video tutorials very useful for me, maybe it will help you too:

[Spring AOP video tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdyLsX0nG30&list=PLE37064DE302862F8&feature=plcp)

Answer (score 2):

The following two tutorials are easy to understand and learn, i think.

[Spring: A Quick Journey Through Spring AOP](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t44746.html)

[Spring AOP tutorials and example codes](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/aop/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

bilash.saha provided a link to a good Java Lobby tutorial already.  Here's [a decent intro to the terminology with a few examples](http://java-questions.com/spring_aop.html).  [mykong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-aop-examples-advice/) also provides a decent introduction with examples that show you what to do, step by step.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good collection of [Spring Video Tutorials](https://sites.google.com/site/freej2eevideotutorial/spring-framework-video-tutorial-spring-tutorial-spring-video-training-spring-lessons-spring-course). It helped me. Hope it will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

A good list of Spring tutorials

1. http://www.springsource.org/tutorials
2. http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-tutorials/
3. http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/spring.html
   4
   . http://simplespringtutorial.com/

A good list of Spring with AOP tutorials

1. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/aop_with_spring.htm
2. http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/aop
3. http://www.javatpoint.com/spring-aop-tutorial

Comment: I'll suggest you to go for www.tutorialspoint.com, good luck.